# No response returned from fetch

Tags: javascript, fetch

I am trying to get data from the API and it doesnot return any value. I have tried to put the apiUrl in the browser directly it works there. Even a get request via postman returns request.

```
fetch(apiUrl)
    .then((response) => {
        let data = JSON.parse(response)
        console.log(data)
        return data;
    })
```

Also in Chrome debugger, there is no request in the network tab as well. I have used the same code earlier to get the response.

Comment: How are you calling this?

Comment: please check this out https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Did you check the browser console for any errors? Did you try `.then(response => response.json())` instead of parsing the response manually? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch

Comment: @VLAZ calling it on a button click,

Comment: @str No error in console. And tried response.json as well as async/await with the same no result.

Answer (score 0):

Calling the API with Fetch gives a promise, and converting it to JSON will return yet another promise, which you need to "await" for again. This is how it should look like

```js
fetch(URL)
  .then(response => response.json())
  .then(json => console.log(json))
```

Comment: JSON.parse(promise) crushes with Unexpected token

Answer (score -1):

```
fetch(apiUrl)
  .then((response) => {
     return response.json().then( res => {
        let data = res;
        console.log(data)
        return data;
     })
})
```

try this

Comment: `response.json()` returns a promise